# How to tackle interior mutability in a struct?

Tags: rust

I have a struct `Screen` that handles the manipulation of windows, drawing to the screen, and handling the input.

One of the methods, that handles the input, is as follows:

```rust
pub fn prompt(&mut self) {
    for e in self.stdin.lock().events() {
        match e.unwrap() {
            Event::Key(Key::Char('\n')) => break,
            Event::Key(Key::Char(c)) => {
                if c.is_alphanumeric() {
                    self.overlay.putc(self.cursor_y, self.cursor_x, c);
                    self.move_cursor(self.cursor_y, self.cursor_x + 1);
                }
            }
            _ => ()
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that `self.move_cursor()` takes a mutable reference to self, and modifies the cursor position within the `Screen`.
The code produces the following error:

```
   --> src/screen.rs:190:25
    |
184 |         for e in self.stdin.lock().events() {
    |                  --------------------------
    |                  |
    |                  immutable borrow occurs here
    |                  immutable borrow later used here
...
190 |                         self.move_cursor(self.cursor_y, self.cursor_x + 1);
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

The methods operate on different members, so it is safe.
I understand the issue and I'm thinking about how to tackle it. One option that I thought of is to wrap every member of the `Screen` in `RefCell` and pass an immutable reference `&self` to every method of `Screen`. This does not seem to me like a good solution, though. I was also thinking to simply use `unsafe {}` but was unable to use it properly in this context.

My question is: what would be the best, or idiomatic, way to handle this; or how to reorganize the struct.

For extra context: I'm drawing to the terminal, using the library `termion`.

Comment: Split the struct and call `move_cursor()` with one substruct.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman thanks, that makes sense. It makes a mess of the API, though. Would it make sense to then create wrappers on the superstruct to make the methods of the substruct accessible?